# How to add disable attribute to a Django <select> form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django choice form:

```
SEASON_CHOICES = (
    ('running', 'Running season'),
    ('next', 'Next season' )
)

class DeterminingForm(forms.Form):
    season = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=SEASON_CHOICES)
```

I want a disabled option in my form. Something like a placeholder with 'Choose an option', just like you see on almost any select form. I don't know how to do this. Any idea?

Comment: add `(None,"Select from following choices")` in SELECT_CHOICES. This should solve your problem. You can read official documentation over [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: This does solve the problem but this would result a few bugs in my program and extra lines of validation

Comment: as per documentation Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display'). Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField

Comment: I didn't have blank=True neither a default, still didnt get the label "-------------". Did I do something wrong above?

Comment: No, if you have set blank=False and default=some_default in modelfield the "-------" will automatically shows. If you don't have both of the conditions then just add a tuple `(None,"Your select message")` inside SELECT_CHOICES. I guess you don't need to write validation manually unless you have set blank=True.